# PhpStorm не компилирует оператор import(SyntaxError: Unexpected token import)

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

На строчке

```js
import React from 'react';
```

выдает ошибку  **SyntaxError: Unexpected token import**. Версия ноды 8.1.4.

[image: Версия es]
[image: Включенный компилятор]

Comment: IDE сообщаете об ошибки? или сервер?

Comment: IDE при запуске сервера

Comment: Накопал, что v8 поддерживает не все функции es6, только стабильные. То есть для компиляции import, export нужен Babel или что-то подобное, верно?